# SyntaxError: missing : after property id jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I am using jquery to do operation of clicking a submit button. I am doing a validation of a form and require just one value from the form, not all.. All seems well, but am getting error..

```
 $('#tabs-1').on('click', '#showme', function(e){


  $("#form13").validate({
         debug: false,
   rules:{
   trainerss:"required",

    },
   messages:{

    trainerss:"Please choose the trainer",
        },
    submitHandler: function(form) {

    $.ajax
   ({

var trainerss=$("#trainerss").val();//error shows this line
var dataString='trainerss='+trainerss;


type: "POST",
url: "action.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,

success: function(response) {
    $('.result14').html(response); 

        }







            });
        }
    });  
    });
```

my form

```
<div id="tabs-1">

    View Trainer Performance<br><br>

    <form id="form13" name="form13" action="" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="myFormsName" value="form13id" id="myFormsName">
    <select name="trainerss" id="trainerss" class="trainerss">
    <option selected="selected" value="">--Select Trainer--</option>
    <br>
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    </select><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Display!" id="submit13" name="submit13"/>
    <br><br>
    </form>
    <div class="result13"></div>
    <input type ="button" id ="showme" class="showme" name="showme" value="Show Member List"/>


    <div class="result14"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!!!
The form validates and the value of trainerss pass on when used for submit button(submit13), but  button showme,shows this error..

Comment: Please before asking indent your code properly. Most of the errors would be solved simply by making the code readable.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Ajax call by :

```
$.ajax
({   
   type: "POST",
   url: "action.php",
   data: {trainerss : $("#trainerss").val()},
   cache: false,

   success: function(response) { //Your treatment
   }
});
```

Comment: will try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$.ajax
   ({
 var trainerss=$("#trainerss").val();//error shows this line
 var dataString='trainerss='+trainerss;
```

to

```
var trainerss=$("#trainerss").val();
var dataString='trainerss='+trainerss;
$.ajax({
```

You can't have code floating like this in an object literal. The javascript compiler looks for a `:` after the first token of the literal object.

Comment: thank you, but  it showin error.. the error is seen here in var trainerss line